# Can TFSBuild replace part of your web.config settings?

Tags: tfs, web-config, tfsbuild

Is it possible for a TFSBuild to replace part of your web.config settings with another section?

Is this generally handled by a copy (overwrite) task on AfterBuild or AfterDropBuild where the parts of the web.config have been extracted out into their own seperate files?

UPDATE Mid '10...

If you're using Visual Studio 2010, it now comes with a new Web Config Transformation feature.

[This is also a related SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2791236/what-is-the-web-debug-config-and-web-release-config-file-for) talks about that also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be looking into the MSBuildExtensions:

http://www.codeplex.com/MSBuildExtensionPack

They have the ability to write XML to config files.  There is also a lot of other useful things they can do.

Hope this helps,

B

Comment: So, out of the box.. the answer is no (unlike out of the box for web deploment projects) .. ??

Comment: No TFS build is just basically the build system.  It has a default build script template that allows you to hook into points in the build process anything after that you have to find an existing task for or write one yourself.