# ASP.NET Web.Config Hidden Features?

Tags: asp.net

Yesterday I found a very useful article on MSDN about Enabling Application-Level Tracing
[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1y89ed7z(VS.85).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1y89ed7z%28VS.85%29.aspx)

```
<configuration>
 <system.web>
  <trace enabled="true" requestLimit="40" localOnly="false"/>
 </system.web>
</configuration>
```

So I would to ask if there are other useful config settings that you recommend learning about?

Comment: happy reading: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dayb112d.aspx

Comment: Voting to close as not a real question because the entire premise is false.

Comment: @John I disagree, it may be something that's not worded very well, but it IS a valid question if rephrased as "What are the potential configurable features of the ASP.NET web.config?"

Comment: @drachenstern: I would still close it, since the answer is trivial. Make the question: how do I learn the potential configurable features, and it will be ok. Then just answer with a few links, and it's all over.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See here and the pages it links to (and the pages those pages link to) to explore various things you can put into web.config.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228147(v=VS.85).aspx

Answer (score 1):

There are technically no undocumented features of the web.config that you should use, and that trace feature is documented.

However, this page may help you: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1fk1t1t0(v=VS.85).aspx or this one http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dayb112d(v=VS.85).aspx

As well as checking the .config files in C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\config and C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727

All the features that you primarily will use are configured in those files or listed as a topic or linked topic on that Microsoft page I linked you earlier.

Answer (score 0):

For one, there is the [web.debug.config and web.release.config](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2791236/what-are-the-web-debug-config-and-web-release-config-files-for).
And there is also a practice of [encrypting connectionstrings in web.config](http://www.beansoftware.com/ASP.NET-Tutorials/Encrypting-Connection-String.aspx)