# What is the use of web.config, web.config.debug, web.config.release?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Can any one please specify in depth about what is the use (when to use)
Web.config,web.config.debug,web.config.release files in asp.net web applications??

Comment: possible duplicate of [What are the web.debug.config and web.release.config files for?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2791236/what-are-the-web-debug-config-and-web-release-config-files-for)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's web.config transformation files that are used to change the web.config for debug and release builds. For example use a different database when debugging and running the release version.

See more information regarding this [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465326.aspx).