# How do you manage web.config files in different projects within same solution when you need shared rules?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, web-config

In my solution, I have 2 projects, call them `Foo` and `Bar`.  When deployed, `Foo` is the root site (http://mycompany.com) and `Bar` is a sub-directory (http://mycompany.com/sub).

When I work on them locally in IIS Express on my local machine, I need to replicate things into web.config of both projects since I work on them separately. For example, I have one of the HMTL5 Boilerplate rules for "cache busting" in my Rewrite rules:

```
<rewrite>
    <rules>
        <rule name="Cachebusting">
            <match url="^(.+)\.\d+(\.(js|css|png|jpg|gif)$)" />
              <action type="Rewrite" url="{R:1}{R:2}" />
        </rule>
    </rules>
</rewrite>
```

If I just leave it in the web.config for `Foo`, then when I work on `Bar`, it's not applied and I get errors since the rewrite isn't happening.  So I've replicated sections into the web.config for both projects.

But when I publish the solution to Azure, I get conflicts because of the inheritance rules since the web.config for `Foo` is in the root.

What is the best way to manage this? I tried to search on this topic but couldn't find this exact problem described.

**Update:**

My `applicationhost.config` for IIS Express is as such:

```
        <site name="Bar" id="3">
            <application path="/" applicationPool="Clr4IntegratedAppPool">
                <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="E:\Code\mycompany\Bar\Bar" />
            </application>
            <bindings>
                <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:65052:localhost" />
            </bindings>
        </site>
        <site name="Foo" id="4">
            <application path="/" applicationPool="Clr4IntegratedAppPool">
                <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="E:\Code\mycompany\foo" />
            </application>
            <bindings>
                <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:50477:localhost" />
            </bindings>
        </site>
```

I tried editing it to make both apps part of the same site, with these changes but no luck. Seems to have broken everything :)

```
        <site name="Foo" id="3">
            <application path="/" applicationPool="Clr4IntegratedAppPool">
                <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="E:\Code\mycompany\foo" />
            </application>
            <application path="/Sub" applicationPool="Clr4IntegratedAppPool">
                <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="E:\Code\mycompany\Bar\Bar" />
            </application>              
            <bindings>
                <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:65052:localhost" />
            </bindings>
        </site>
```

Comment: Can both sites not share the same linked configuration file?

Comment: They can't share the same web.config file since the sub-site has settings in it that don't apply to the parent site (like connecetion strings)

Answer (score 0):

Make your root site (http://mycompany.com) as a website in IIS, and your sub-directory as virtual directory in IIS.

IIS shares the Rules defined in root website ('s web.config) with the virtual directory.

Comment: I'm using IIS Express locally and deploying to Azure in production.  How do I configure IIS Express like this? Is it a project/solution setting within VS?

Comment: which IIS Express version you are using?

Answer (score 0):

Use `web.debug.config` and `web.Release.config` to manage the development and release environment difference. For more please follow [this SO POST](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2791271/405673) or [this MSDN blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdevtools/archive/2009/05/04/web-deployment-web-config-transformation.aspx)

Comment: I tried messing around with this, but this seems better suited to dealing with different configurations due to a difference between dev and prod (such as connection strings). In this case, it's more related to IIS not running the projects together as a single site.