# How to use different webconfig configurations based on release type in Visual Studio?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, web-config

In a .net visual studio project I have

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="sqlname" connectionString=""/>
</connectionStrings>
<appSettings>
    <add key="mykey" value="myvalue" />
</appSettings>
```

I can then start the project from VS code as `debug` and `release` as you all know. But I was wondering if there was a way to set up the web.config like this

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add mode="debug" name="sqlnametest" connectionString="..._test"/>
    <add mode="release" name="sqlname" connectionString=""/>
</connectionStrings>
<appSettings>
    <add mode="debug" key="mykeytest" value="myvaluetest" />
    <add mode="release" key="mykey" value="myvalue" />
</appSettings>
```

And it automatically uses the entries here with mode=debug if I start it in debug mode. And uses the entries here with mode=release if I start it in release mode (or publish).

This way I don't need to keep commenting it out the sections based on where I want to deploy.

Thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2791236/what-are-the-web-debug-config-and-web-release-config-files-for

Comment: Thanks that works.